# hazelcast map put operation not working

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am using hazelcast -2.5 in a cluster.  I have a map (key: String, value: ArrayList of user defined objects).  I am able to put/remove fine in most places but in one specific part of my code, the put operation fails silently (the key string used for the put operation is unique and the ArrayList is not empty either).  No exceptions are thrown.  In case there was a lock involved, I even tried tryPut and that call gave me a true return value.  Right after the put operation, I tried printing out the keySet for the map but cannot see the key I just inserted - the size of the map has not changed either (yet the tryPut gave me a true return value and I'm reasonably sure the string I am using for the key is unique - and I am hoping the binary form for the key is unique as well).  If the binary form for my key is not unique, I am assuming that the tryPut should return a false return value or at least replace the previously added key/value with the new key/value pair (unless I misinterpreted the docs).

```
boolean putVal = testMap.tryPut(this.testObj.UUID, testEntity, timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);   //timeout is 2000L or 2 seconds in this case
```

Any thoughts on troubleshooting this or figuring out if the binary form for my key is causing the issue will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do a get. And see if there is any value associated with that key. If not, the put should be successful.

Comment: thanks - I actually tried that multiple times within 2-3 seconds of the put operation and it returns a null value for me (which is how I got to the point that the put might be failing).  I already tried printing out the keyset right after the put operation and the key is not there.  It most likely could be an issue with my code though I would like to confirm what the issue is.  Does it matter how long the (String) key is for the map?

Comment: I think I misinterpreted your suggestion.  I will try that, and if there is no value, I will proceed with the put operation and share the results

Comment: Pilot Error (egg on my face)!  The put was working fine.  I had some test code which was calling get on the map which in turn was calling the load in the store-load implementation for the map (the value was already in the DB by then through another map's store load implementation - this map's store implementation is empty).  Thanks Fuad for responding.